# How to hide the Navigation Bar for Option Menu and let the Content be Fullscreen till the Bottom

Tags: android, kotlin, uinavigationbar, fullscreen, android-optionsmenu

Hiding of the android system bars (status bar and navigation bar) is working. By adding `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN` the status bar was removed completely.
The navigation bar is not visible, but ***there is a gap at the bottom of the screen***. Also when I ***click on the options menu, the navigation bar will appear***.

So, how can I remove the navigation bar completely? There should not be a placeholder for it and it should not be visible while the options menu is showing.

**picture of the navigation bar problem:**

[image]

This is the code I am using in *MainActivity.kt*:

```
override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
    hideSystemUI()
}

override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if (hasFocus) hideSystemUI()
}

private fun hideSystemUI() {

    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    )

    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            //or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

*activity_main.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*app_bar_main.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

*content_main.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*nav_header_main.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle"
            android:id="@+id/textView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

Comment: I added it. It is almost the setting of a new navigation drawer activity by android studio.